# SQL Query Needed - to Get data for previous date always, where date column is split into multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get rows where date is equal to Previous day,

**Table Schema** as below,

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE students (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  gender TEXT NOT NULL,
  xYear INTEGER,
  xMonth INTEGER,
  xDay INTEGER,  
);
```

-- **Sample Table** ---

| id | name | gender | xYear | xMonth | xDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ryan | M | 2023 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | Joanna | F | 2023 | 1 | 12 |
| 3 | ro | M | 2023 | 1 | 11 |
| 4 | han | F | 2023 | 1 | 12 |
| 5 | ta | M | 2023 | 1 | 11 |
| 6 | run | F | 2023 | 1 | 11 |
| 7 | radha | M | 2023 | 1 | 12 |
| 8 | cena | F | 2023 | 1 | 12 |

---- **Expected result** ---- considering today is 13th Jan, so i want data for 12th Jan----

| id | name | gender | xYear | xMonth | xDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ryan | M | 2023 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | Joanna | F | 2023 | 1 | 12 |
| 4 | han | F | 2023 | 1 | 12 |
| 7 | radha | M | 2023 | 1 | 12 |
| 8 | cena | F | 2023 | 1 | 12 |

not sure , how to achieve this.

Comment: Do not store the dates in this form. Store it as a date type

Comment: That is something which is not in my control. We have this table and we have to use this table; to work on my next tasks.

Comment: What have you tried?  This looks a lot like a homework question at the moment

Comment: I have never worked on SQL, this is my first time, so it might sounds basic query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite clear this is a bad DB structure and the date should be stored as date in one single column instead in future.

Creating the desired result can be achieved by building a date out of those three columns and then check this date is yesterday.

There are lots of functions which can do this job, here one way with `CAST` and `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT 
id, name, gender,  
xYear, xMonth, xDay
FROM students
WHERE 
  CAST(CONCAT(xYear,'-',xMonth,'-',xDay) AS DATE) 
    = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

You can also try above without the `CAST` and check if this is executed faster:

```
SELECT 
id, name, gender,  
xYear, xMonth, xDay
FROM students
WHERE 
  CONCAT(xYear,'-',xMonth,'-',xDay) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/24sGzqHy)

Comment: CAST is excess.

Comment: I am getting error between word "INTERVAL" and "1"

Comment: @RajneshThakur Post **complete** error message text. It seems that your DBMS is NOT MySQL...

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the columns to a stringand convert it to a date and compare it with "yesterday"

```
select  * 
from students 
where STR_TO_DATE(concat(xYear, '-',xMonth, '-',xDay), "%Y-%m-%d")=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tgfrXZg9S3Zd2rNCiG1Ym/1)

Comment: getting error: near "1": syntax error

Comment: Which version of `mysql` do you use? Have you copied my statement or written by your own?